# Declaring a constant of generic type that conforms to protocol

Tags: json, swift, swift4, codable

Alright, tinkering around with Swift 4 by writing some networking code with their new Decodable protocol. The following errors out with several compiler errors:

```
// A lot has been stripped out of this for brevity, so we can focus on this specific constant
struct APIRequest {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let decodableType: <T.Type where T : Decodable>    // Compiler errors here

    // This function compiles and runs successfully when I pass it in explicitly (by removing the above constant)
    func decodeJsonData<T>(_ data: Data, for type: T.Type) throws -> T where T : Decodable {
        return try decoder.decode(type, from: data)
    }
}
```

The decodableType is supposed to be the 'Type' of any struct/class that conforms to the Decodable protocol (i.e. User.self where User conforms to decodable or codable). How do I tell the compiler this?

Edit: To put it another way, I would like to write the code like this...

```
struct APIRequest {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let decodableType: <T.Type where T : Decodable>    // Not sure how to declare this type

    func decodeJsonData(_ data: Data,) throws -> Decodable {
        return try decoder.decode(decodableType, from: data)
    }
}
```

Which means holding the generic parameter from the first code block inside of a constant on the struct. I just don't know how to write out the type correctly in Swift.

Comment: "Which means holding the generic parameter from the first code block" what first code block?

Comment: Correct... by 'first code block' I meant the first gray code area on this page. The generic parameter in the first code block being the 'for type' parameter that gets passed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your struct to have a generic type, it has to be declared as such, and not as a member as with what you were trying:

```
struct APIRequest<T: Decodable> {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    func decodeJSONData(from data: Data) throws -> T {
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

Or you can just limit the generic type to the scope of the function:

```
struct APIRequest {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    func decode<T: Decodable>(from data: Data) throws -> T {
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not help me, as I do not want the struct to conform to the generic type (it's not intended to). I just want to store the Type of the class that conforms to Decodable so I can pass it through the decoder before handing it back to the caller.

Comment: I think I might have been a little unclear in my original question, sorry about that. I've added an edit to clarify (hopefully) the intent of the question.

Comment: This answer is almost certainly correct. "as I do not want the struct to conform to the generic type." This struct doesn't conform to the generic type. It is just parameterized by it. "I just want to store the Type of the class that conforms to Decodable so I can pass it through." Parameterizing on the type (as this answer does) exactly stores the type in order to pass it back. What calling code are you envisioning that this answer doesn't address. Getting the constant you describe is possible, but generally useless in your example.

Comment: Ahh 'parameterized by it' were the magic words for me, I'm not sure why I didn't understand this the first time I looked at it (beyond the fact that I'm just starting to understand generics mechanics). This answer/comment plus this doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html finally pushed me over the edge in understanding.